# assembly own object at runtime

Tags: c++, json, object

I want create object at run-time  as in JavaScript:

```
person=new Object();
person.firstname="John";
```

I'm going to parse json and save to object. Methods will be known in advance and compiled.
I created this simple example and I would like to know if I'm going the right way.

adding and call method by string;  function male and female will be added to object as  methods to object.

Now in object is property gender, but later I want to do the same as with the functions. by methods `setProperty` and `getProperty` declared in Object.  is it a good idea?

```
typedef struct method
  {
  (void)(*method_fn)(Object * _this, string params);
  string method_name;
  } method;




 class Object{

 private:
      vector<method> methods;

 public:
     string gender;
     Object(){};
     ~Object(){};
     void addMethod(method metoda);
     bool callMethod(string methodName,string params);

 };


     void  male(Object *_this,string params) {
        _this->gender="Male";
    }

    void female(Object* _this,string params) {
        _this->gender="Female";
    }





 void Object::addMethod(method metoda)
        {
        methods.push_back(metoda);
        }


 bool Object::callMethod(string methodName,string params){

         for(unsigned int i=0;i<methods.size();i++)
            {
                if(methods[i].method_name.compare(methodName)==0)
                    {
                     (*(methods[i].method_fn))(this,params);
                    return true;
                    }
            }
         return false;
     }
```

using and it is work.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Object *object1 = new Object();
    Object *object2 = new Object();


    method new_method;

    new_method.method_fn=&male;
    new_method.method_name="method1";


    object2->addMethod(new_method);


    new_method.method_fn=&female;
    new_method.method_name="method2";

    object2->addMethod(new_method);


    object1->callMethod("method1","");
    object2->callMethod("method2","");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly OK.  You've created dynamic containers for your methods and their associated names.  This is A LITTLE like what a dynamic language would do, behind the scenes.

What you can do to improve it is use hash maps, for more speed.  For example:

```
typedef void (*Method)(Object& _this, const string& params);
typedef std::unordered_map<string, Method> NameToMethodMap;
typedef std::unordered_map<string, string> NameToValueMap;

class Object {
private:
    NameToMethodMap methods;

public:
    NameToValueMap attributes;

    void addMethod(const std::string& name, Method& method) {
        // TODO: check that name isn't in there first
        methods[name] = method;
    }
};

int main() {
    Object o;

    o.attributes["gender"] = "male";
}
```

Comment: More speed assumes that there are a very large number of methods, such that log(N) is large, and that the hash function is sufficiently fast.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using a `map`, and using references:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object() {}
    ~Object() {}
    typedef void (*Method)(Object& _this, const std::string& params);
    void setMethod(const std::string& name, Method fn) { methods[name] = fn; }
    bool callMethod(const std::string& name, const std::string& params);

private:
    std::map<std::string, Method> methods;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> properties;
};

bool Object::callMethod(const std::string& name, const std::string& params)
{
    // Look for it.
    // Note: in C++11, you can do this instead:
    //     auto methodIter = methods.find(name);
    std::map<std::string, Method>::iterator methodIter = methods.find(name);

    if(methodIter == methods.end())
        return false;

    // Found it.
    (*(methodIter->second))(*this, params);
    return true;
}
```

Note that I added `properties` which does the same thing as `methods` except it maps names to strings instead of functions. This replaces your `string gender;` stuff.

Anyway, just some small changes to your main function, to remove the need for a method structure:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Object *object1 = new Object();
    Object *object2 = new Object();

    object1->addMethod("method1", &male);
    object2->addMethod("method2", &female);

    object1->callMethod("method1", "");
    object2->callMethod("method2", "");

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I used the `std::` prefixed versiojns of the standard type names because you should *never* have `using namespace std;` or similar in a header file.